# Is there an old text of Mein Shalosh?

Tags: blessing, birkat-meeyn-shalosh

I’ve seen essentially three different versions of Mein Shalosh, or more specifically, the Al Hamichya.

Some versions add “v’al HaKalkalah” as the final words , some add it as both the final words and immediately before the final line and some say it in neither places.

I am curious, is there any text at all regarding what earlier generations said? Did rishonim ever write down their version of the Mein Shalosh/Al Hamichya Bracha?

Comment: We have dozens of versions. Are you looking for any Rishon in particular, or any text in particular?

Comment: Looking for anything that will help guide me in not getting confused which way to say it each time! Lol

Comment: See Aruch Hashulchan Orach Chaim 208:1 and Mishnah Berurah Orach Chaim 208:50 who say not to say it either time. (They follow Shulchan Aruch over Tur.)

Comment: The 'yeshiva' minhag was to say it like this. ועל המחיה ועל הכלכלה האט דער גאון נישט געזאגט so you both said it and didnt say it!

Answer (score 3):

I'll post a few, copied straight from the Bar Ilan Responsa Project. (There are many, many more, and even those who don't write their entire text sometimes write the ending.)

> **ספר הלכות גדולות סימן א - הלכות ברכות פרק שישי**

> על המחיה ועל הכלכלה ועל ארץ חמדה טובה ורחבה שרצית והנחלת את אבותינו לאכול מפריה ולשבוע מטובה ולהודות לך עליה רחם על עמך ועל עירך ועל היכלך ועל מקדשך ובנה ירושלים עיר קדשך במהרה בימינו ונאכל מפריה ונשבע מטובה ונברכך עליה בקדושה ובטהרה בכבוד ב"א ה' על המחיה ועל הכלכלה.

> **בית הבחירה (מאירי) מסכת ברכות דף מד עמוד א**

> על המחיה ועל הכלכלה ועל תנובת השדה ועל ארץ חמדה טובה ורחבה שהנחלת את אבותינו רחם ה' אלהינו על ישראל עמך ועל ירושלים עירך ותבנה אותה מהרה והעלנו לתוכה ונאכל מפריה ונשבע מטובה ונברכך עליה בקדושה ובטהרה בא"י על הארץ ועל המחיה ויש שמוסיפים בה כי אל טוב אתה כנגד הטוב והמטיב

> **ספר אבודרהם ברכת בורא מיני מזונות**

> ברוך אתא ה' אמ"ה על המחיה ועל הכלכלה ועל תנובת השדה ועל ארץ חמדה טובה ורחבה שרצית והנחלת את אבותינו לאכול מפריה ולשבוע מטובה רחם ה' אלהינו על ישראל עמך ועל ירושלים עירך ועל ציון משכן כבודך ובנה את ירושלים עיר קדשך במהרה בימינו והעלנו לתוכה ושמחנו כי אל טוב ומטיב אתה ברוך אתה ה' על הארץ ועל המחיה ועל הכלכלה.

> **ספר אור זרוע חלק א - הלכות סעודה סימן קפא**

> והוא ברוך אתה ה' אלהינו מלך העולם על המחיה ועל הכלכלה ועל תנובת השדה ועל ארץ חמדה טובה ורחבה ברית ותורה חיים ומזון על שהוצאתנו מארץ מצרים רחם ה' עלינו על ישראל עמך ועל עירך ועל נחלתך ועל היכלך ועל מזבחך ועל מקדשך ובנה עירך בימינו ונחמנו בה כי אל טוב ומטיב אתה ברוך אתה ה' על הארץ ועל המחי'.

> **ברכות מהר"ם קיצור ברכות מהר"ם**

> ברוך אתה ה' אמ"ה על המחיה ועל הכלכלה ועל תנובת השדה ועל ארץ חמדה טובה ורחבה שרצית ו(ש)הנחלת לאבותינו לאכול מפריה ולשבוע מטובה, רחם ה' אלקינו עלינו ועל ישראל עמך ועל ירושלים עירך ועל מקדשך ועל מזבחך ועל נחלתך, ובנה ירושלים עיר קדשך במהרה בימינו והעלינו בה ושמחנו בתוכה כי אתה טוב ומטיב לכל, ברוך אתה ה' על הארץ ועל המחיה.

Comment: Everyone should take all these quotes with a grain of salt. Common texts like "mein shalosh" are a favorite place for copyists and editors to "fix" what they believe to be typos, based on their own version of that text. You need to be very careful about what manuscripts you rely on when comparing these. (Nothing against the poster of course, just general advice to readers.)

Comment: Interesting that three of them write את אבותינו instead of לאבותינו.

Comment: @Kazibácsi leining tomorrow morning וְהָיָ֗ה בְּיוֹם֙ הַנְחִיל֣וֹ אֶת־בָּנָ֔יו אֵ֥ת אֲשֶׁר־יִהְיֶ֖ה ל֑וֹ 
 and from a few weeks ago וַעֲבַרְתֶּם֘ אֶת־הַיַּרְדֵּן֒ וִישַׁבְתֶּ֣ם בָּאָ֔רֶץ אֲשֶׁר־יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֵיכֶ֖ם מַנְחִ֣יל אֶתְכֶ֑ם and וְהוּא֙ יַנְחִ֣יל אוֹתָ֔ם אֶת־הָאָ֖רֶץ אֲשֶׁ֥ר תִּרְאֶֽה all show a direct object (and each in a Rishon!)

Comment: @DoubleAA But then from where does the ל version come from? I've been here and there, but I don't remember having seen the את version.